# search functions without some special function call in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I have a very large source code(>10,000lines) to change, with some function with fn_i_dont_want, I don't need to change, all other functions I must do some changes.So it's very hard to find such functions in such a large source code.
For example:

```
int foo_i_dont_want()
{
  fn_i_dont_want()
}

 int foo_i_want1()
{
  fn()
  fn1()
}

int foo_i_want2()
{
    fn()
    fn1()
    ....
}
```

I want vim to search all function I want, `foo_i_want1`, `foo_i_want2`, the condition is I don't want function with function call `fn_i_dont_want`.

I've tried to use vim regex like

```
  /{\_.\{-}fn_i_dont_want\_.\{-}}
```

or

```
  /{\_.*fn_i_dont_want\_.*}
```

But everything fails, it gets worse when there is some function like this:

```
int foo_i_dont_want()
{
    struct bar = {0,0};
     fn_i_dont_want();
}
```

and vim searches for everything in the pair of bracket{}.

So can somebody help me?

Comment: The obligatory question: ***What do you want to do with those matches?***

Answer (score 0):

Parsing a complex programming language with regular expression is bound to be incomplete and problematic. Instead:

- either use the refactoring capabilities of a real IDE, or
- if you have to do this in Vim use `:substitute` with the `c`onfirm flag, and manually accept / decline each match position after inspecting it